# What is a slide-to-lift-off called?

Tags: guitar, technique, violin

At the end of the first solo the guitarist slides backwards an the lifts off the note. I'm pretty sure that is a thing violinist also do. Is there a term for that, I do seem to want to think so?

Solo start 2 minutes 40 seconds.

Comment: If somebody could edit the link to auto start @ 2minutes 40, that would be swell.

Comment: Is there a reason why *you* didn’t edit the link to start at 2:40?

Comment: Could not figure out how to do it on my tablet.

Answer (score 2):

Looks and sounds to me like a simple slide down to nothing. There's no note following, which would need a pull-off at the end of the slide, so 'gliss' would do. Written as a straight line down - the former way could be a wavy line. The line would start next to the note played, and go down, here, to the bottom of the stave.

All that volume, and no muted strings! Pretty good!

Comment: Musescore (and possibly other notation software) has a mark called "slide down out" that fits the use case and description.